# Different answer from power equations

Tags: ohms-law, math

Imagine a circuit like this: 6 red leds with a Vf of 1.8V are wired in series with a resistor. Vcc is 12v.
To acheive a current of 10mA, you would do (12-10.8)/0.01 = 120 so 120 ohm resistor.

Now to calculate the power dissipated over that resistor I have three options:

1. P = VI = 12 * 0.01 = 0.12W
2. P = V^2 / R = (12)^2 / 120 = 1.2W
3. P = I^2 * R = (0.01)^2 * 120 = 0.012W

So, which one is it?

Comment: Use the same value of V (that's 12 - 10.8) you used to calculate the resistor. Now all 3 equations should give the same value.

Comment: C'mon clever editor guys it was right in the first place when the Op said (12 -10.8) volts.

Comment: I've rolled it back!!!

Comment: aaah I see, **6** LEDs... oh gosh, I should be less tired.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *Now to calculate the power dissipated over that resistor I have three
> options...... So, which one is it?*

The correct answer is #3 because #1 calculates the total power dissipated in the resistor and LEDs and #2 is just plain wrong because it assumes 12 volts is across the resistor.

Comment: *#2 assumes 12 V across the resistor* so does #1.

Comment: #1 does not assume 12 volts is across the resistor @MarcusMüller - it uses 12 volts but as the full supply to the resistor and LEDs.

Comment: Right, I see. So in summary, the value of V is wrong since it uses the total voltage in the circuit and not just the voltage across the resistor. The third equation is true since it did't use the incorrect V.